# Creating a Oracle-style Package in MariaDB 10.3.12

Tags: oracle, plsql, mariadb

We are converting an Oracle database to MariaDB 10.3.14.

As of 10.3.5

> The PL/SQL stored procedure dialect (enabled with sql_mode=ORACLE) now
>   supports Oracle style packages.

Please help us understand what is wrong with this syntax to create a package.

```
SET sql_mode=ORACLE;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SS_GEN2 AS
  TYPE studentListRecord IS RECORD
      (
        STUDENT_ID    INT,
        USER_ID       INT,
        CREATED_WHEN  TIMESTAMP,
        YEAR_ID       INT,
        PROGRAM_ID    INT,
        FIRSTNAME     VARCHAR(150),
        LASTNAME      VARCHAR(150)
      );
  TYPE studentListTable IS TABLE OF studentListRecord;
  FUNCTION GET_ACTIVE_STUDENT_LIST( TARGET_PROGRAM_ID IN INT DEFAULT 0, TARGET_YEAR_ID IN INT DEFAULT 0) RETURN studentListTable PIPELINED;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Where else should we look for help?

EDIT:

Here is the error message. Not particularly helpful.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'PACKAGE SS_GEN2...

Comment: Please elaborate - what is your *exact* problem? Do you get a compile-time error, run-time error, or something else entirely?

Comment: Thank you. Edited to include error message.

Comment: [If I'm reading the docs correctly](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-package/) the only things you're allowed to put in a MariaDB package are function and procedure definitions, so perhaps it's the RECORD data type definition that's making it unhappy. YMMV.

Comment: In addition to what @BobJarvis said, the SQL_MODE=ORACLE does only support a subset of PL/SQL - see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql_modeoracle-from-mariadb-103/